# Selecting the maximum “n” values

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector

If I have the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

    struct Features{ int F1, F2, F3, F4; };

    int criterionFunction(Features const& features) {
        return
            -2*features.F1*features.F2
            +3*features.F1
            +5*features.F2
            -2*features.F1*features.F2*features.F3
            +7*features.F3
            +4*features.F4
            -2*features.F1*features.F2*features.F3*features.F4; }
```

How can I apply `transform()` to find the first **THREE** *max values*?

Thanks.

Comment: Why `transform`? `nth_element` or `partial_sort` seems more appropriate.

Comment: Please be more specific. This could be a linear optimization problem, or maybe you just want to select some elements from an existing list.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example using `nth_element` with a simpler feature object and criterion function (to reduce clutter):

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>

typedef int Features;

int criterionFunction(Features features) {
  return features;
}

int main() {
  std::vector<Features> v { 0, 4, 2, 5, 4, 3, -2, 1 };
  std::nth_element(v.begin(), v.begin() + 3, v.end(),
                   [](Features a, Features b) {
                       return criterionFunction(a) > criterionFunction(b);
                   });
  std::copy(v.begin(), v.begin() + 3,
            std::ostream_iterator<Features>(std::cout, " "));
}
```

For your original `Features` object, it might be useful to cache/memoize the results of the `criterionFunction` to prevent duplicate calls.

Note that `nth_element` does not sort the elements in the two partitions; if you want the first three elements in sorted order, use `partial_sort` instead.

Comment: Please note that `nth_element` does _not_ result in the 3 items _in order_. Partial sort would do that.

Comment: @sehe The OP did not ask for them to be ordered :)
I'm adding a remark though.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. It's not what `std::transform` does.

`transform` applies a single function to every element in the sequence. It does not select specific elements.

Answer (score 1):

With a combination of `std::transform`, `std::multiset`, and an insert iterator you could.

```
vector<Features> v;
...fill it up
multiset<int> ms;
transform(v.begin(), v.end(), inserter(ms, ms.begin()), criterionFunction);
```

Then the three max values are the last three elements.