# C++ - Selecting the maximum "n" values

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector, max

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Selecting the maximum “n” values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11603786/selecting-the-maximum-n-values)

If we have the following code:

```
    struct Features{ int F1, F2, F3, F4; };

    int criterionFunction(Features const& features) {
        return
            -2*features.F1*features.F2
            +3*features.F1
            +5*features.F2
            -2*features.F1*features.F2*features.F3
            +7*features.F3
            +4*features.F4
            -2*features.F1*features.F2*features.F3*features.F4; }
```

What way do you suggest that can be used ti retrieve the **maximum THREE values** after applying the `criterionFunction()`?

Thanks.

Comment: Maximum three values of what?

Comment: @DanielFischer Apparently top 3 `Features` elements out of a `vector<Features>` order by `criterionFunction(that)`.

Comment: In general terms: 1) Build list, 2) Sort list, 3) Fetch top 3 items: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/list/sort/

Comment: For the future, you will be better off asking what you want to achieve  in the first place, rather than asking about a particular solution. This question makes more sense than the one marked as duplicate (and yet, one of them needs to be closed and they are basically the same (and this has the greater number of votes to close...)

Comment: I've edited the title of the original question to match the title of this one.

Answer (score 3):

I think you can use `std::partial_sort` for that.  For example:

```
 #include <algorithm>

 bool criterionGreater(Feature const& left, Feature const& right) { return criterionFunction(left) > criterionFunction(right); }

 std::partial_sort(yourVector.begin(), yourVector.begin() + 3, yourVector.end(), criterionGreater);
```

Then the first three things in yourVector should be the three greatest.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest storing the values in a `std::priority_queue`, so that the top three elements are available directly.

If the elements are already stored, you can still use a priority queue. Iterate over the sequence, and if `x` is the current element

- If the priority queue has less than 3 elements, add `x` to the queue
- Else, if the bottom element of the queue has greater value than `x`, do nothing
- Else add the element to the queue and remove the bottom one

Everything is provided by the standard library, you just have to provide your comparison function

```
bool operator<(const Features& x, const Features& y)
{
    return criterionFunction(x) < criterionFunction(y);
}
```